# Count specific word in specific column across all rows

Tags: mysql

Using PDO and PHP, how would I efficiently count all occurrences of a certain word (fruit) across all rows of a certain column, in this case column 'text'?

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
| id | fruit     | text                                        |
|  1 | Apple     | Apple,Banana,Date,Elderberry,Mango          |
|  2 | Banana    | Fig,Apple,Cranberry,Pineapple               |
|  3 | Cranberry | Apple,Cranberry,Huckleberry,Mango,Pineapple |
|  4 | Date      | Banana,Yuzu,Raspberry,Cranberry,Apple       |
```

I must end up with a result like this:

```
| id | fruit     | occurrences |
|  1 | Apple     | 4           |
|  2 | Banana    | 2           |
|  3 | Cranberry | 3           |
|  4 | Date      | 1           |
```

The table has approx. 200.000 rows.

I tried fetching each fruit with PHP and running following query (found on stackoverflow) on each result:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(text) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(text, 'Apple', '')) / CHAR_LENGTH('Apple') AS fruit_count FROM fruits
```

But it does not give me 4 apples for id 1, instead 0.

Comment: Just a note - the solution you've tried to implement is based on counting the values in a single row, not across all rows in your table.

Comment: @MatsLindh ok. Does a solution for searching across all rows exists?

Comment: Yes. You can check my answer for that.

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try following way:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

select @len:= group_concat(text separator ',') from t;

select
id,
fruit,
ROUND (   
        (
            CHAR_LENGTH(@len)
            - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE (@len, fruit, "") ) 
        ) / CHAR_LENGTH(fruit)        
    ) AS occurrences
    from t
    group by fruit
   ;
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92d95/1/1)

Comment: isn't there a limit of 1024 characters for `group_concat`?

Comment: you can increase that using `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please check the demo as well.

Comment: If the above answer has solved your problem, please mark it as answer.